# How to set matplotlib backend at vscode

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

Ubuntu 19.10,
VScode 1.42.0,
python 3.7.6,
anaconda 4.8.2,
matplotlib 3.1.3

It seems that `plt.show()` doesn't work, because the current matplotlib backend is `agg`.
Running from the terminal, I can use `Qt4Agg`, but from the integrated terminal inside VScode I cannot change from `agg`.

Tried the following:

1. add `backend: Qt4Agg` at matplotlibrc
2. `__import__("matplotlib").use("Qt4Agg")`
   `__import__("matplotlib").use("Qt4Agg", warn=False, force=True)`
   *ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt4Agg' which requires the 'qt4' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running*
3. `plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')`
   same *ImportError*
4. `export MPLBACKEND=Qt4Agg` before running the command

But, nothing worked. Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have PyQt4 installed? I would try PyQt5, though.

Comment: Yes, it is installed. Tried PyQt5, too. It is probabaly a VScode issue, because it is working from the terminal, using the same anaconda env.

Comment: Same problem here, could you solve it?

Comment: Yes, there is an accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but it looks like your integrated terminal is running in headless mode. Changing `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` to `true` in settings should fix it.

Comment: I can't remember why I had set that to false years ago, but yes, this worked. Thanks.